# How do I show that is is orthogonal to every vector in the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for some help with the following question. I have found the answer to question a) Let $\pi$ be a plane with the equation $x-2y+2z=0$. I need to find the matrix $P$ such that $\mbox{proj}_{\pi}(u)=Pu$ for all $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$P =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 - n_x n_x & -n_y n_x  & -n_z n_x \\
-n_x n_y & 1-n_y n_y  & -n_z n_y \\
-n_x n_z & -n_y n_z  & 1-n_z n_z \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
8/9 & 2/9  & -2/9 \\
2/9 & 5/9  & 4/9 \\
-2/9 & 4/9  & 5/9 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

However I am having some trouble with question b) Find the projection of $b=\begin{pmatrix}
1
\\1
\\1
\end{pmatrix}$ onto the plane in (a) and verify that $b−Pb$ is orthogonal to
every vector in the plane.

My solution to b so far:

$Pb=\begin{pmatrix}
8/9
\\11/9
\\7/9
\end{pmatrix}$ and when I calculated $ b - Pb $ I got $\begin{pmatrix}
1/9
\\-2/9
\\2/9
\end{pmatrix}$ but How do I show that is is orthogonal to every vector in the plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ is in the plane $\pi$, the only thing you know about it is that $x-2y+2z = 0$.  What is the dot product of such a vector with $\begin{pmatrix} 1/9 \\ -2/9 \\ 2/9 \end{pmatrix}$?

From your comments, it seems like you assumed $(x,y,z) = (1,-2/9,2/9)$, but that vector is not in $\pi$.  Instead, you need a **generic** vector $(x,y,z)$.  You cannot assign values to those variables, but since the vector is in $\pi$ you do know that they satisfy the one equation $x-2y + 2z=0$.

Comment: when I dotted them together I got 9/9 but how is that orthogonal?

Comment: @geohelp: Check your algebra.

Comment: 1/9 + 4/9 + 4/9 = 1?

Comment: @geohelp: see edited answer.

Comment: ah I see what you are saying so for instance 0,1,1 is in the plane and 0,1,1 dotted with b-pb is = 0

Comment: @geohelp: You got it.  You just need to make a generic argument without choosing values for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: how do I made a generic comment without choosing values?

Comment: @geohelp: You leave them as variables.

Answer (score 0):

A vector orthogonal to a plane $ax+by+cz=d$ is $(a,b,c)$. So if $b-Pb$ is parallel to $(1,-2,2)$ then you're good.

Comment: how do I know if its parallel?

Comment: For $v\in\Bbb R^3$ to be parallel to $u\in\Bbb R^3$ there must exist $c\in\Bbb R$ such that $v=cu$. So two vectors are parallel if one is a scalar multiple of the other.